# « Après sept mois de gestation » ou « à sept mois de gestation » ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

> Elle est née à sept mois de gestation.
>
> Elle est née après 7 mois de gestation.

Quelle préposition est correcte et pourquoi ?

Comment: « À l'issue d'une gestation de 7 mois » ?

Comment: @Toto Troisième option ?! Je n'y ai pas réfléchi:-)! Donc mes deux phrases sont toutes deux incorrectes ?

Comment: Pas tout à fait mais leurs occurrences dans [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+sept+mois+de+gestation%2Capr%C3%A8s+7+mois+de+gestation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20sept%20mois%20de%20gestation%3B%2Cc0) sont très faibles, l'une des deux n'apparait même pas !

Comment: A priori les 3 formulations (question + remarque de Toto) sont correctes et seront comprises de manière similaire. Pour le côté idiomatique, ngram peut donner une indication, en ce qui me concerne je ne trouve aucune des 3 particulièrement incongrue.

Comment: « Elle est née à sept mois. » — « Elle est née après sept mois de gestation » — « Elle a eu une gestation de sept mois »

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première proposition:

> Elle est née à sept mois de gestation.

n'est pas idiomatique (voir plus loin). Ce qui est courant, c'est :

> *Elle est née à sept mois*.

ou, moins souvent :

> Elle est née à sept mois de grossesse.

> Elle est née au bout de sept mois de grossesse.

La deuxième proposition :

> Elle est née après 7 mois de gestation.

est techniquement correcte avec ces deux réserves :

1. on recommande d'éviter d'écrire les "petits" nombres en chiffres;
2. *gestation* est un terme de biologie plutôt réservé aux femelles des mammifères.

> Une femelle pleine/gravide **[met bas](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_bas)** au bout de x semaines/mois de **[gestation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gestation)**

mais :

> Une femme enceinte **[accouche](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accoucher)** au bout de x mois de **[grossesse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grossesse)**.

Pour parler de la naissance d'une petite fille, on préférera donc :

> Elle est née après sept mois de grossesse.

Answer (score 1):

« Après sept mois de gestation » est formel et aussi convenable dans le parler de tous les jours ; « à sept mois de gestation » est aussi correct mais moins explicite. On trouve un exemple de ce dernier usage,  dans le contexte même de la gestation et dans la langue pas si ancienne, c'est à dire quand même considérée comme moderne, mais plus vraiment contemporaine ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IVviAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA12&dq=%22%C3%A0+six+mois%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj51Lzcv6vnAhVZCWMBHTJYCLMQ6AEIoAEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20six%20mois%22&f=false)).

- — PREMIER CONSUL « Un enfant né à six mois six jours peut-il vivre ? »
  — FOURCROY « Il est reçu que non »
  …
  — FOURCROY « Les uns à six semaines, les autres à … »

Voici un exemple dans la [langue contemporaine](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3LMi05CpbSwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Institut+de+l%27%C3%A9levage%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdhOvlxqvnAhUd6OAKHdbGCIMQ6AEIKDAA#v=snippet&q=%204%20mois&f=false) (p. 499).

- Les vaches chez lesquelles un avortement à plus de 4 mois de gestation ou une mise-bas auront été induites doivent ensuite être particulièrement surveillées car le risque de rétention placentaire –et donc de métrite– est plus élevé.